# Is it possible to rename a report version?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to (re)name report versions, can't find any info about this possibility.

Why:
I have a report with 6 date valid values and want to generate report view which will contain 6 versions, each with different date valid value.
The version names are however only displaying the date of report generation, which makes sense, although this is confusing for the user, since the version name (date of generation) doesn't correspond with the report date valid value.

Alternatively, if I could put a little note/description to each report version, that would solve my problem too.

Any pointers are much appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have chosen to schedule the report to run and save output, and you have told it to save the last six instances.

I think for what you are asking, you should create six report views -- each one with its own "report date valid value" defined in the prompts section of the properties.  The report views can be named appropriately and scheduled.  You'll probably want to save only the last one instance of each.

I don't know what you mean by "report date valid value".  These may be the first of the month, Mondays, etc. but I don't know.  So I'm going to be a bit vague.

Here's the process for each report view:

1. Right-click on the report and select "Create report view".
2. Change the name to something meaningful - `My Report - Report Date Valid Value 1`.
3. Right-click on the new report view and select "Properties".
4. Go to the Report tab.
5. Uncheck "Prompt for values".
6. For "Current values" click on "Set values".
7. Click "Set".
8. Set the prompts for this report date valid value.
9. (at the bottom) Click Finish (or whatever your prompt page labels the Finish button).
10. Go to the Schedule tab.
11. Click "Create schedule"
12. Set schedule properties as appropriate and Save.  You shouldn't need to set the prompt values here since we set them on the Report tab.

Do that for all of your "Report Date Valid Value" values.

Comment: Hello dougp, yes it's exactly how you described it in your first sentence. 

I could create separate shared views and named them by the particular date valid chosen, although this will not work if I want to schedule generating these report views.

Comment: New Cognos user?  I'll reword my answer.

Comment: Hello dougp, many thanks for this detailed guide. I will definitely solve my problem.
As for the meaning of "report date valid value" - it's a date valid value from a date prompt in the report. I meant that the report/report view output versions are named by the date and time of their generation and do not correspond to the date valid value I have chosen in the date prompt when generating this version.